# Invalid Cast Exception While converting from smallint to Int32?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

The code below fills the properties of my model from the `DataReader`.I made some properties `Nullable` and it isn't working since then.

```
foreach (var property in _properties)
{
    property.SetValue(model, null, null);

    if (columnsInDataReader.Contains(property.Name.ToLower()))
    {
        if (!(_dataReader[property.Name] == DBNull.Value))
            property.SetValue(model, _dataReader[property.Name]);
    }
}
```

The property is `Int32?` and the database column is `smallint` and the conversion fails.

Comment: What did you make nullable?

Comment: Smallint is inside the range of int. Are you sure this is the point where it fails ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What *exactly* is not working. Please provide all relevant information, in particular the actual exception and where it is thrown tigether with the values of the relevant instances.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 some int properties of the model which weren't nullable before.

Comment: @Florian Michel yes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere .SetValue throws exception complaining about the int16 and Nullable int32

Comment: So the type of the property is `Int32?` (`Nullable<int>`), while that one returned by the datareader is `Int16`, correct?

Comment: @himbrombeere yes

Comment: Conversion from `Int16` to `Int32?` should work without any problems. Can you please add where the exception is being thrown exactly and what the value of `_dataReader[propertyName]` is at that moment?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  it fails here ==> property.SetValue(model, _dataReader[property.Name]); Exception you know.

Answer (score 2):

Even if an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions) from `short` to `int?` do exists, the issue here arises from the fact that the data reader returns a **boxed** `short`, for which you need an [**unboxing conversion**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#unboxing-conversions). In this specific case, the conversion is from `object` to a value type (`int?`).

The paragraph that matches your situation is the last of the cited section: since the object returned is a boxed `short` and not a boxed `int`, the cast fails.

As a concrete example, compare these two snippets:

```
short src = 42;
int? dst = (int?)src;

object src = (short)42;
int? dst = (int?)src;
```

While the first one succeeds, the second throws an `InvalidCastException`.

In your case, no explicit cast occurs, however the call to `SetValue` applies similar conversion rules, and therefore fails.

Summing up, in order to have the call succeed, you must choose the type of the property among those that are castable at runtime from the type of the extracted object, such as `short` and `short?`.

Comment: Ugly though it is `int? dst2 = (int?)(short)src2;` will compile too.

Comment: @Chris It will compile, but in the scenario of the question you have no compile-time information about the target type and even a direct cast isn't enough. However, one should emit a dynamically generated method that unboxes and casts as needed... Nothing impossible, but very annoying and fragile.